# Formula to give itemized sum

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following sheet ([link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11bgXSyP7ldXgW0QauQ6jOGnA3LG7-qSBEq6Hk6wM9Xg/edit?usp=sharing)). What formula would yield the itemized sums in B2, C2, and D2?

To calculate the value in B2, the formula should check cells B5:B10 and sum the corresponding values from A5:A10 for non-blank cells. Hence: `30+45+30=105`.

I have tried `ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B5:B10 != ""), sum(A5:A10))` which results in *Formula parse error*.

[image: Itemized Sum]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the numbers in column B are not to used (thats what i figured out from your example).
you can use sumIf:

```
=SUMIF(B5:B10,">0",A5:A10)
```

so this will check if the cell in column B is greater than 0, then it will add its corresponding value from column A.

[image]

please note that if you put a character in the B column the SUMIF will not consider it because we are using ">0" as criterion, instead use ISBLANK.

hope it helps.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank! In MS Excel it was possible to lock part of a reference so in copy-pasting the formula it would not change relative to source-destination. Is a similar feat possible in Google Sheet?

Comment: yep same as excel use the $ sign, EX: $A$2